# Why is a word added to Yishtbach in Shabbat?

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, nusach-sefard

According to Nusach Sfard (Ashkenazi) the word Uvechen (ובכן) is added before Yishtabach (ישתבח). Although the content of the Yishtabach tefila is same as every regular day. What is the reason for the addition of this word  Uvechen (ובכן) only on Shabat and why?

Comment: There are hundreds of words added to Yishtabach on Shabbat in every nusach, at least in all rites that begin the blessing with "Nishmat Kol Chai..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this Minhag mentioned in [Kaf-Hachayim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.48.1.11?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he):

עלו מושיעים וכו' והיה ה' למלך וכו' ישתבח שמך וכו' ולא יאמר פסוק שמע ישראל קודם ישתבח וכו' כאשר נמצא בקצת סידורים הנדפסים, גם אין לומר ובכן ישתבח שמך וכו' אא"כ הוא בשבת שאומרים נשמת כל חי ואח"כ אומר ובכן ישתבח שמך וכו' גדולה גבורה תהלה ותפארת.

Think he means that in a regular day this word has no meaning and therefore you shouldn't say that as it is a Hefsek,
but on Shabat after Nishmat we say and with that (ובכן) referring to the obligation of all creatures to bless (חובת כל היצורים), his name will be blessed (ישתבח).

Comment: I heard that the word Uvechen (ובכן) is one of G-d names. This resembles to the tefila of Yamim Noraim such as ובכן תן פחדך, ובכן צדיקים יראו וישמחו. I couldn't find any source for it, except for this: בברכת קדושת השם לראש השנה ויום הכיפורים, במילה "ובכן" שמופיעה ארבע פעמים מכוונים בשלוש הפעמים הראשונות פסוק אחד מפסוקי "ויסע ויבא ויט", ובפעם הרביעית את השמות היוצאים מכל הפסוקים יחד.[34]

 link: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A2%22%D7%91